# Convert certificate from p7c to cer

Tags: certificate

how to convert a certificate from .p7c to .cer extension?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, we find the solution (on windows xp):
double click the file >> click copy on file >> save the file in cer format.

Answer (score 11):

I know this is a very old question.

But on Windows 10 or Windows Server 2012 R2, if you double click on a `.p7c` file,  Windows will try to open `p7c` file with `wab.exe` (Windows Contact), which is wrong.

What I had to do was **rename the `p7c` file into `p7b`**, only then it will be recognized as a certificate file.

Then I can double click on it and Windows will open it with `certmgr`, as shown below and export it to Base64 `.cer` file :

[image]